# Calculate Areas of breaks under a beta distribution in r

Tags: r, distribution, beta-distribution

Given the following beta distribution

```
x <- seq(0,1,length=100)
db <- dbeta(x, .25, .43)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x,db))+scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by=.1))
```

how can I find the area under breaks 0 to 1 by 0.1 intervals. Not cumulative area just area for that specific break. For example the break 0.2 to 0.3 would have only that area inclusive and not previous areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area between the breaks is the difference between the cumulative area for the two endpoints.  So that for example, the area between 0 and 0.1 is

```
pbeta(0.1, 0.25,0.43) - pbeta(0, 0.25,0.43)
```

To get all of the areas, just apply this to the list of breaks

```
breaks = seq(0,1,by=.1)
sapply(1:10, function(i) pbeta(breaks[i+1], 0.25,0.43) - pbeta(breaks[i], 0.25,0.43))
```

Answer (score 1):

G5w's answer is better for this question. In general, though you can use `integrate` to get the area under functions for specific intervals. For instance, for `dbeta` between 0.2 and0.3, you could use

```
integrate(dbeta, .2, .3, shape1=.25, shape2=.43)
0.05982106 with absolute error < 6.6e-16
```

To get this for each interval of width 0.1 from 0 to 1, put this into an `sapply`.

```
myAreas <- sapply(seq(0, .9, .1),
                  function(x) integrate(dbeta, x, x+.1, shape1=.25, shape2=.43)[[1]])
```

This results in a vector of these values

and compare the results to G5W's suggestion.

```
all.equal(pbeta(0.1, 0.25,0.43) - pbeta(0, 0.25,0.43), myAreas[1])
```